# Creating child processes in std::threads on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, fork, popen

I have a program written in C++ for Windows which is a native application for a browser extension. Basically it receives messages from the browser through `stdin` and sends back responses through `stdout`. The messages are URLs that need to be downloaded with an external application such as `curl`, and the responses are the progress/completion of these downloads.

My program flow is as such:

1- There is a main loop that constantly reads `stdin` and received messages from the browser

2- For each message the main loop creates an `std::thread`. The thread is given the URL to download and is started and then the main loop goes back to listening for new messages.

3- In the thread I spawn a child process, say `curl.exe`, using `CreateProcess()` and keep reading its output.

4- Now these threads need to send the download progress to the browser, which they do by writing to the program `stdout`. Since multiple threads need to write to it at the same time I have a function protected with an `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>` and the threads write to `stdout` using this function.

Now I want to port this program to Linux and I was hoping to simply replace `CreateProcess()` with `popen()` but I did a Google search about whether it's thread safe or not and even tho I couldn't find a definitive answer, most answers suggested that it is not. Apparently it uses `fork()` under the hood and [forks and threads don't get along well](https://web.archive.org/web/20170812180443/http://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/threads-and-fork-think-twice-before-using-them).

It looks like the Linux way is to `fork()` and then use pipes to communicate between the main program and the forks but that would require for me to change the whole structure of the program since it's currently based on threads. Also I don't know how I can maintain my main loop and at the same time read the pipes from all these forked child processes. I can't imagine doing that without using a thread which gets us back to the first problem.

So I was wondering if there's another way to do this?

Here's a *simplified* version of how the program works:

```cpp
std::mutex theMutex;

int main()
{
    while(true)
    {
        char* url = new char[message_length];
        fread(url, sizeof(char), message_length, stdin);
        
        std::thread th1(download_thread, url);
        th1.detach();
    }
    
    return 0;
}

void download_thread(const string url)
{
    /* create the process */
    CreateProcessW(
            "curl.exe",
            "curl.exe url",
            NULL,
            NULL,
            TRUE,
            processFlags,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            &siStartInfo,
            &piProcInfo);
    
    /* keep reading the output of the process until it exits*/
    const int BUFSIZE = 1024;
    char buf[BUFSIZE];
    unsigned long bytesRead = 0;
    bSuccess = FALSE;

    while(true)
    {
        bSuccess = ReadFile(h_child_stdout_r, buf, BUFSIZE, &bytesRead, NULL);

        if(!bSuccess || bytesRead<=0)
        {
            break;
        }
        
        string output(buf, buf+bytesRead);
        write_to_stdout(msg);
    }
}

void write_to_stdout(const string msg)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(theMutex);
    
    const unsigned int message_length = msg.length();
    fwrite(msg.c_str(), sizeof(char), message_length, stdout);
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

Comment: (1) There is absolutely nothing thread-unsafe about `popen`. (2) It is perfectly OK to call `fork` from a multi-threaded program. It may do unexpected (to you) things if you don't know what you are doing, but calling `exec` after `fork` is 100% safe and reliable.

Comment: As an aside, why launch a `curl` process instead of just using `libcurl` directly from within the thread?

Comment: @G.M. It's not always curl. The user also specifies the program to launch, I'm using curl as an example here.

Comment: Pay attention to the bit about file descriptors in that article you linked to.  IMHO, you'll get more problems from that in MT programs that fork() than from data races.  Be sure to supply the `"e"` flag in the `popen()` call!  Or any call that opens a file descriptor.  All the POSIX APIs have a `FD_CLOEXEC`-like flag.  And the "C" APIs like `fopen()` have something like `"e"` to use it.  But C++ APIs like `std::ofstream` do not!

Comment: @TrentP That did catch my eye too. Will do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [[res.on.objects]](https://eel.is/c++draft/res.on.objects)
> <sup>1</sup> The behavior of a program is undefined if calls to standard library functions from different threads may introduce a data race. The conditions under which this may occur are specified in [[res.on.data.races]](https://eel.is/c++draft/res.on.data.races)

> [[res.on.data.races]](https://eel.is/c++draft/res.on.data.races)
> <sup>2</sup> A C++ standard library function shall not directly or indirectly access objects ([intro.multithread]) accessible by threads other than the current thread unless the objects are accessed directly or indirectly via the function's arguments, including this.
> <sup>3</sup> A C++ standard library function shall not directly or indirectly modify objects ([intro.multithread]) accessible by threads other than the current thread unless the objects are accessed directly or indirectly via the function's non-const arguments, including this.

So `popen` cannot possibly introduce a data race.

```
$ man popen
  ...
ATTRIBUTES
       For an explanation of the terms used in this section, see attributes(7).
   ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────┬───────────────┬─────────┐
   │Interface                                           │ Attribute     │ Value   │
   ├────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼─────────┤
   │popen(), pclose()                                   │ Thread safety │ MT-Safe │
   └────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴───────────────┴─────────┘
```

Comment: So let me know if I got this right: using `fork()` with threads could cause problems explained in the link I posted in my question, *HOWEVER* since I am not forking myself, and none of *MY* code is being executed in the fork it's alright if I use `popen()` even if it uses `fork()` under the hood. Correct?

Comment: Yes, pretty much so.

Comment: It's not inherently unsafe to call `fork()` in a MT program.  `popen()` calls fork, and does so in an MT-safe way.  You could call `fork()` yourself and do so in an MT-safe way too.  What matters is what the child process that is forked does.  A simplified version is that it should do nothing but call `exec()` and most certainly should not allocate any memory.  The latter, not allocating memory directly or indirectly, is somewhat easier in C than C++.  E.g., is the name of program to `exec()` stored in a `std::string`?  Is an argument appended to this string?  That's an allocation.